# Should I allow to access our APIs from clients other than my native app?

Tags: web-services, authentication, microservices

I am writing a web application that consists of a web frontend developed in angular as well as a mobile application.
I am defining a microservice architecture that exposes several web APIs. Most of them requires the user to be authenticated, but others expose data publicly.
Now, with this approach everybody could potentially access the APIs using different clients, for example postman. 
Of course for most of them they will have to present credentials and get an access token.
I wonder if this is the right way to go. That a user could register himself into my platform using a different client from my application, because at the end it is only an API that is publicly exposed.
Also for the authenticated one, should I not bother from where the request come as long as a user is authenticated?
So at the end, when providing such architecture should we allow users to access our API and data regardless from the used client?

Answer (score 0):

Here some food for thoughts:

Use a *backend for frontend*: you map a subset of your APIs in a new backend and introduce additional authentication and authorization policies. Here you could perhaps remove the access to the public endpoints or enforce authentication also for them.

User should be able to access your APIs as soon as she has the right permissions and is authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The application is a single page application and also the mobile app is designed to use the same APIs. So theoretically each authenticated user with the correct roles could access those APIs from any http client. The registration endpoint should stay public to allow anybody to sign up. But of course they could sign up using any http client. So, anyways there is no possibility to restrict the access to my own clients, right?

Comment: Of course you can add a rule that checks on the http client. Be aware that this is only a string that can be changed using tools like `curl`, `postman` or even in the web browser itself.

Comment: I thought of implementing a check based on some parameter given by the client. But that would be reported in the source code of both the web and mobile app. So, anyway that could be found and used. That would be an approach that could anyway be bypassed easily, right? I could also go for this approach but it doesn't completely protect the usage of the APIs